# Can't get the new computer past POST, continually rebooting

Tags: boot, power-supply

I’ve have been having power problems with a new computer that I recently put together. The system included:

- Thermaltake Level 10 GTS case
- Asus Sabertooth Z77 motherboard
- Asus Geforce GTX 660ti video card
- 32GB Corsair Vengence XMP memory
- Thermaltake Water 2.0 Extreme cpu cooler
- Samsung  840 Pro 128GB SSD
- Western Digital Velocitor 1TB HD
- LG Blu-Ray Optical Drive
- Seasonic X-Series (SS-650KM3) PSU

When I first started the system up it began a cycle of repeatedly shutting down and starting up.  The timing of this shutdown/startup sequence was  around 7 or 8 seconds per cycle.  I cannot get the system to power up long enough to get to get past POST to the boot screens.

I stripped the computer down to just the motherboard, CPU and Seasonic power supply.  I disconnected/removed the XMP memory,  CPU Cooler, SSD, HD, LG Blu-Ray,  and ASUS  video card; and  tried to power up again and the system still cycles on and off.  I then received replacements for both the motherboard and CPU, reinstalled then and am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: It could just be a broken power button.. push on, stays stuck down, after 5 secs it shuts down.

Comment: Check the error lights on the motherboard to see if any are lit

Comment: If it still happens after replacing motherboard and CPU, the problem can be in the case: a faulty power button, a problem with the power supply... try changing that.